# ¿Cuáles son las reglas para "nadie" + indicativo?

Tags: traducción, indicativa, literatura

En *El Silmarillion*, alguien ha construido esta oración:

> "y tú, Melkor, verás que ningún tema puede tocarse que no tenga en mí
>   su fuente más profunda, y que ***nadie puede*** alterar la música a mi
>   pesar."

Aquí, el énfasis está en que "no existe alguien que pueda" en lugar de "todos no pueden". Por lo tanto yo no creo que esta traducción sea válida.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, that's not subjunctive, that's plain old indicative (present).

The literal translation (back) to English of that last sentence would be:

> *(...) y que **nadie puede** alterar la musica a mi pesar.*
>   (...) and that **nobody can** alter the music in my despite.

You're probably being confused by the original using *"no theme may be played (...) **nor can any** alter the music*", which makes you try to wrongly identify "any" with *"nadie"*.
I hope the simpler version above makes it clearer.

Comment: Por eso creo que está mal. Debe ser subjuntivo.

Comment: Ahh, Me diste la respuesta sin querer. El subjuntivo tiene que estar en una cláusula subordinada mientras que "poder" está en la cláusula principal

Comment: puede es subordinada por verás, que no acarrea el subjunctivo, pero una oración subordinada de un sujeto que no existe como "no hay ... que" o no existe ... que" previene el subjunctivo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66154/discussion-between-user135711-and-walen).

Comment: @walen - Thanks for your patience in this thread. I agree, indicative is the right tense ("Verás que nadie puede alterar la música"). //  I thought you might want to know that the phrase you're looking for is "your efforts to use it are *worthy of praise.*  (*Appraisal* is a little bit different.)

Comment: @walen - I had to look up TIL -- interesting.  (I'm horribly ignorant of modern slang.) // I forgot to say, there's also *praiseworthy*.  (Good word if there were a Translation Gold at ELU.)